# DIV Tag Content Can't Show

Tags: jquery, html

I have an something problem with my code below :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
(function($)
    {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajaxSetup(
            {
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function() {
                $('#loading').show();
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#content').show();
            },
            success: function() {
                $('#content').show();
            }
        });
        var $container = $("#content");
        $container.load("online_users.php");
        var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
            $container.load('online_users.php');
        }, 1500);
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>


<style type="text/css">
        .content-area
        {
            overflow:hidden;
            height: 100% !important;
            width: 150px;
            overflow-y: hidden;
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }

        .jspVerticalBar
        {
            width: 8px;
            background: transparent;
            right:0px;
        }

        .jspHorizontalBar
        {
            bottom: 5px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 8px;
            background: transparent;
        }

        .jspTrack
        {
            background: transparent;
        }

        .jspDrag
        {
            background: url(images/transparent_black.png) repeat;
            -webkit-border-radius:4px;
            -moz-border-radius:4px;
            border-radius:4px;
        }

        .jspHorizontalBar .jspTrack,
        .jspHorizontalBar .jspDrag
        {
            float: left;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .jspCorner
        {
            display:none
        }

        .tables
        {


        }
    </style>
```

---

```
<div id="content">
 bla bla bla
</div>
<div id="center">
 bla bla bla
</div>
<div id="right">
 bla bla bla
</div>
```

Content from `div id="left"` successfully showed.

I am using jquery for div left to refresh data automatically.
Why the content from `div id="center"` and `id="right"` can't be shown?

I try to delete jquery, and content from `div id="center"` and `div id="right"` showed.

In online_users.php, that's include the CSS (content-area) and some JS to give a scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var $container = $("#left");
```

instead of this

```
var $container = $("#content");
```

I suppose you're using the wrong ID to change

What about change

```
 .content-area
        {
            overflow:hidden;
            height: 100% !important;
            width: 150px;
            overflow-y: hidden;
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }
```

to

```
 .content-area
        {
            height: 100% !important;
            width: 150px;
        }
```

Comment: Hi Ronn0, Updated with your suggest. But div id center and right still can't show. Any idea ?

Comment: That's kinda strange. Is there some CSS with div { display: none; } or something?

Comment: Hi Ronn0, I've updated my question, that's include CSS and some JS. The function is to give scroll for data in table. May any stuck with the code ?

Comment: try the modifications in script I posted. and replace "test3.html" with your "online_users.php" filename

Comment: it works well here for me. I tried the code provided with a small test page  "test3.html" page load. may be some some error in online.php? try loading a static page

Answer (score 0):

```
   <script>
(function($)
    {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajaxSetup(
            {
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function() {
                $('#loading').show();
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#content').show();
            },
            success: function() {
                $('#content').show();
            }
        });
        var $container = $("#content");
        $container.load("test3.html");

        var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
            $container.load('test3.html');
        }, 900);


        var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
            $("#center").load("test3.html");
        }, 1200);

        var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
            $("#right").load("test3.html");
        }, 1700);


    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

hope this helps